# Gradle ResolutionStrategy in root build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

Is it possible to specify a ResolutionStrategy in the root `build.gradle` that gets applied in subprojects? I can only get it to work if the ResolutionStrategy is added directly in the subproject's `build.gradle` file.

```
subprojects {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if(details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j') {
                    details.useVersion '2.15.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I put that in my root `build.gradle` and run `./gradlew :subproject:dependencies`, the strategy is not applied. However, when I put the same configuration block inside of the subproject's `build.gradle`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me as you have it with Gradle 7.3 in a quick test project I wrote:

```
➜  ./gradlew :module-a:dependencyInsight --dependency log4j

> Task :module-a:dependencyInsight
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:2.15.0 (selected by rule)
   variant "compile" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-api
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar (compatible with: classes)
      org.gradle.category            = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.environment     = standard-jvm
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 17
   ]

org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:2.14.1 -> 2.15.0
\--- compileClasspath
```

Comment: Ah, it seems like somehow the spring boot dependency management plugin is overriding this. Maybe it's getting executed in a certain order that negates the ResolutionStrategy. In non-spring projects, it works without changes. In spring projects, I have to also set `ext['log4j2.version'] = '2.15.0'` and then everything works

Comment: The Spring Dependency Management plugin is a bit 'greedy', so you can't exactly mix both styles (Spring/Native Gradle). See this excellent talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AADeX1AEmzU